# dataframe check column length and update value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lambda

0

I have a column which should have data in below format:

xxxxx-xxx

But I see for some records hyphen is missing so I need to update the data for these records. Data I see is following below format:

xxxxx-xxx ( for few records) xxxxxxxx ( for remaining records)

For the records which are in xxxxxxxx format, I need to update the data and insert hyphen (-) at 6th position to convert it to expected format (xxxxx-xxx). Can someone please advise how to avoid this error:

Code :

```
 df['col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[:5] + '-' + x[5:]
     if len(x) != 9 and '-' not in x else x)
```

Error:

TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Comment: `df['col'].str[:4] + '-' + df['col'].str[-3:]`

Comment: @QuangHoang updated some typos in the question. error is for Nan record it can not check length

Comment: Fill na with Blank

Comment: `df['col'].str[:4].str.cat(['-']*len(df)).str.cat(df['col'].str[-3:])` or `df['col'].apply(lambda x: x[:4]+'-'+x[-3:] if isinstance(x, str) else x)`

Comment: The following uses `pd.mask`: `df['col'].mask(~df['col'].str.contains("-").fillna(False), df['col'].str[:5] + "-" + df['col'].str[-3:])`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) :

```
df["col"] = df["col"].replace(r"(.{5})-?(.{3})", r"\1-\2", regex=True)
```

> Regex : [[*demo*](https://regex101.com/r/NaHAF8/1)]

Output :

```
print(df)

         col  col (new)
0  12345-678  12345-678
1        NaN        NaN
2   abcdefgh  abcde-fgh
```

Used input :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"col": ["12345-678", np.nan, "abcdefgh"]})
```